# Why am I getting this TypeError: AgglomerativeClustering.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'affinity'?

Tags: python, jupyter

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import FeatureAgglomeration
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 7 , linkage = "average" , affinity = "cosine" )
```

...And here is the resulting error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 4
      1 from sklearn.cluster import FeatureAgglomeration
      2 from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
----> 4 model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 7 , linkage = "average" , affinity = "cosine" )

TypeError: AgglomerativeClustering.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'affinity'`
```

I tried updating all the necessary libraries and updating the pip but still nothing. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looking the documentation seems that your are looking for the `distance` paramter.

This should work.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import FeatureAgglomeration
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 7, linkage = "average", metric = "cosine" )
```

EDIT: documentation link [AgglomerativeClustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html)